# JavaScript variable scope in geolocation function

Tags: javascript, scope

I am trying to use javascript to get a user's geolocation so i can then use that information as a parameter in another section of javascript code, however I can't get the scope right.

This is my code. Doing the alert inside the success function works fine, but if i try to access var lat anywhere outside the function, i get undefined value. How would I go about fixing this?

```
var lat; var long;
function success(position) {
lat = position.coords.latitude;
long = position.coords.longitude;
alert(lat);
}

function error(msg) {

}

if (navigator.geolocation) {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);

} else {
  error('not supported');
}
```

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of **async**! You can't do that.

Comment: I don't see where you are trying to reference `lat` outside of `success()`.

Comment: @gilly3 - i had it after the if else statement, then moved it inside the success function. It only works inside the success function. I guess I'm looking for some way of waiting till the value is returned before trying to access it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want your code to work like this:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error); 
alert("Your position is " + lat + ", " + long + ".");
// do some more stuff with lat and long
```

But, `success()` has not been called yet, so `lat` is still undefined.  **That's what your success handler is for.**  All the code that needs to be executed after you've retrieved the location goes in the success handler.  This would work:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
    success(position);
    alert("Your position is " + lat + ", " + long + ".");
    // do some more stuff with lat and long
}, error);
```